# How to convert xls to xml file using java and springmvc?

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, file-upload, download

I want to make a web-based app that can convert an xls file to xml file using java and springmvc.

For example, I have an xls file like this:

Person.xls

[image]

Here is the pojo :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class File {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "filename")
    private String filename;

    @Column(name = "content")
    @Lob
    private Blob content;

    @Column(name = "content_type")
    private String contentType;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private Date created;
```

And it is the expected output:

[image]

I have made the upload and download functions and it works well.
But I'm stuck at how to produce an xml file when the download button is clicked.

I would really appreciate and welcome any idea, solution, or suggestion to solve this problem.

Best regards,

Yunus

Comment: you would probably want to use apache poi to read the xsl file so that you can convert the data to xml.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

I've tried to use apache poi to convert xsl file to xml, but it is desktop-based not web-based.I wonder how to implement it to web-based.

Thank you.

Comment: umm, what?  are you trying to write this in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The best example i had read long back by [mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-excel-file-via-abstractexcelview/)